# Linking a MapServer layer to GeoWebCache with a different projection than the default ones

Tags: mapserver, geowebcache

I'm somehow having a hard time connecting a standalone GeoWebCache (1.15.0) to MapServer (camptocamp docker-mapserver, version unknown). MapServer itself runs fine. Due to the 'map=' parameter, the MapServer layer can't be loaded from the geowebcache.xml config file. The `GetCapabilities` have to be loaded automatically which can be defined in the geowebcache-core-context.xml file (as described here https://github.com/GeoWebCache/geowebcache/issues/52).

```xml
<bean id="gwcWMSConfig" class="org.geowebcache.config.GetCapabilitiesConfiguration">
<constructor-arg ref="gwcGridSetBroker">
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg value="http://*********/?map=/pathtomapfile/myfile.map&amp;SERVICE=WMS&amp;VERSION=1.1.1&amp;REQUEST=GetCapabilities">
  <description>The URL to the WMS GetCapabilities document, notice &amp; , port is normally 8080</description>
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg value="image/vnd.jpeg-png8">
  <description>The formats to support for all layers read for the above document</description>
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg value="3x3">
  <description>Metatiling factors, 3x3 is usually a good compromise for vector data</description>
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg value="map=/pathtomapfile/myfile.map">
  <description>
          Vendor parameters, these are appended to every request sent to the backend.
          If you use MapServer you probably want to set this to "map=name". Leave the value attribute empty if you don't need
          to add any vendor specific parameter.
      </description>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg value="false">
      <description>Whether to allow cached=false to specificed for certain requests</description>
    </constructor-arg> 
  </bean>
```

Where can I define the projection of the layer when loading it automatically with this configuration from geowebcache-core-context.xml? My MapServer layer is in EPSG:3857. By default, GeoWebCache got two grid sets; EPSG:900913 and EPSG:4326. In the geowebcache.xml config file, I've created a new gridSet EPSG:3857 (attached at the end). How can I tell gwcWMSconfig in geowebcache-core-context.xml to use another projection than the default ones?

Or am I missing something else here? I simply can't load the layer with GeoWebCache, but it works fine when using MapServer only.

MapServer test request:

```
http://*********/?map=/mapfiles/test.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/vnd.jpeg-png8&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=testlayer&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&SRS=EPSG:3857&STYLES=&BBOX=-10789377.645435471,4221930.382996488,-10633009.853472639,4378298.1749593215
```

GWC test request:

```
http://*********/geowebcache/testlayer?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/vnd.jpeg-png8&TRANSPARENT=true&gridSet=EPSG:3857&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG:3857&STYLES=&BBOX=4221930.382996488,-10789377.645435471,4378298.1749593215,-10633009.853472639
```

Somehow it creates a different bounding box. I tried to change `alignTopLeft` as well as `yCoordinateFirst` but that didn't do anything. And when I manually change the values of the bounding box (using the ones from the MapServer request inside GWC request), I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Not sure what exactly is going on here. I don't think that my 3857 `gridSet` is being used as the layer is simply not configured with it. I'm glad for any help and hints.

Here's my GWC gridSet:

```xml
 <gridSet>
  <name>EPSG:3857</name>
  <srs>
    <number>3857</number>
  </srs>
  <extent>
    <coords>
      <double>-2.003750834E7</double>
      <double>-2.003750834E7</double>
      <double>2.003750834E7</double>
      <double>2.003750834E7</double>
    </coords>
  </extent>
  <alignTopLeft>false</alignTopLeft>
  <resolutions>
    <double>156543.03390625</double>
    <double>78271.516953125</double>
    <double>39135.7584765625</double>
    <double>19567.87923828125</double>
    <double>9783.939619140625</double>
    <double>4891.9698095703125</double>
    <double>2445.9849047851562</double>
    <double>1222.9924523925781</double>
    <double>611.4962261962891</double>
    <double>305.74811309814453</double>
    <double>152.87405654907226</double>
    <double>76.43702827453613</double>
    <double>38.218514137268066</double>
    <double>19.109257068634033</double>
    <double>9.554628534317017</double>
    <double>4.777314267158508</double>
    <double>2.388657133579254</double>
    <double>1.194328566789627</double>
    <double>0.5971642833948135</double>
    <double>0.2985821416974068</double>
    <double>0.1492910708487034</double>
    <double>0.0746455354243517</double>
  </resolutions>
  <metersPerUnit>1.0</metersPerUnit>
  <pixelSize>2.8E-4</pixelSize>
  <scaleNames>
    <string>3857:0</string>
    <string>3857:1</string>
    <string>3857:2</string>
    <string>3857:3</string>
    <string>3857:4</string>
    <string>3857:5</string>
    <string>3857:6</string>
    <string>3857:7</string>
    <string>3857:8</string>
    <string>3857:9</string>
    <string>3857:10</string>
    <string>3857:11</string>
    <string>3857:12</string>
    <string>3857:13</string>
    <string>3857:14</string>
    <string>3857:15</string>
    <string>3857:16</string>
    <string>3857:17</string>
    <string>3857:18</string>
    <string>3857:19</string>
    <string>3857:20</string>
    <string>3857:21</string>
  </scaleNames>
  <tileHeight>256</tileHeight>
  <tileWidth>256</tileWidth>
  <yCoordinateFirst>false</yCoordinateFirst>
</gridSet>
```